# How to handle API response errors in async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to better understand error handling while using async/await, third party libs, and external APIs.

Given the following pseudo-code:

```
const createConnectionRequest = async (args) => {
  try {
    const { data } = axios.post(url, args);

    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

My understanding is the `throw` would occur a result of the `axios.post` failing rather than an issue with my request.

If the response from my API was 200 but included an error of some sort, eg.

```
{
  status: 200,
  error: 'Invalid fields supplied',
}
```

Would I throw this error in the `try` block and expect a parent calling function to `catch` it?

```
const createConnectionRequest = async (args) => {
  try {
    const { data } = axios.post(url, args);
    if (data.error) {
      throw new Error(data.error);
    }

    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}

...

const processor = async () => {
  try {
    await createConnectionRequest(...);
  } catch (err) {
    // handle error from API response here
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: you are right, except that you don't need try catch in createConnectionRequest method

Comment: There is no sense if you `catch` and re`throw`. If you can't handle it don't catch it.